# Can Ant be used to embed variable AngularJS templates?

Tags: eclipse, ant, angularjs

I want to embed a variable amount of text files (AngularJs templates) at a specific point of a given text file (`./WEB-INF/app.html`) but except modifying the file saving it as another file (`./index.html`?.
The files I want to embed all have file names ending with `*.ng.html` and are all in a subfolder of `./assets/templates/`.

Also I want to write text before and after the embed file (To make AngularJS recognise that they are templates). This text should consist of both static text and the file names relative to the working directory.

This is a possible structure of a working directory:

```
(index.html) (generated after building)
--assets
  --templates
    --general
      about.ng.html
      contact.ng.html
      home.ng.html
    --users
      userlist.ng.html
--WEB-INF
  app.html
```

**Can this be done using Ant? If not, how could I do this at build-time in Eclipse?**

To further illustrate my intentions, here are examples:

./WEB-INF/app.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
@INSERTION_POINT@
</head><body></body></html>
```

./assets/templates/general/about.ng.html

```
This is a test.
```

./assets/templates/general/contact.ng.html

```
You can contact me at: <a href=mailto:mail@example.com>mail@example.com</a>
```

./assets/templates/general/home.ng.html

```
Welcome.<br>
Click a link to explore.
```

./assets/templates/users/userlist.ng.html

```
<ol>
<%= "{{#userlist}}" %>
  <li>
    {{username}}
  </li> <%= "{{/userlist}}" %>
</ol>
```

**After building,** I want `./index.html` to look like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/assets/templates/general/about.ng.html">
This is a test.
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/assets/templates/general/contact.ng.html">
You can contact me at: <a href=mailto:mail@example.com>mail@example.com</a>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/assets/templates/general/home.ng.html">
Welcome.<br>
Click a link to explore.
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/assets/templates/users/userlist.ng.html">
<ol>
<%= "{{#userlist}}" %>
  <li>
    {{username}}
  </li> <%= "{{/userlist}}" %>
</ol>
</script>
</head><body></body></html>
```

I figured out that I can get a list of the files I want to embed using:

```
<fileset dir="war/assets/templates">
  <include name="**/*.ng.html"/>
</fileset>
```

When I have the final string, I could replace my placeholder and save the output to a new file probably like this:

```
<copy file="WEB-INF/app.html" tofile="index.html">
  <filterset>
    <filter token="INSERTION_POINT" value="??foo??"/>
  </filterset>
</copy>
```

But how do I get the string I want to have to pass as a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

definitely not what you're looking for... sorry... but might look into a Javascript oriented build tool ([Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)) and integrate that with eclipse (or even run it from ant if you're trying to keep your builds the same in java and javascript.)

Though this may not be exactly what you're looking for, you're guaranteed lots of community support if you stick to the standards.

Comment: That actually sounds great! I sensed I shouldn' be using Ant for what I'm up to.